# Where do the points (-1,3) and (2,1) come from?

Tags: linear-programming

I now understand how the green area is obtained from the set definition below in point 2, but how is that set itself constructed? More precisely, where do the points $(-1,3)$ and $(2,1)$ come from?

[image]

Comment: They are two points on the lines $3x_1+x_2=0$ and on $-x_1+2x_2=0$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_1,x_2)$ is a point in $R^2$ that's better than $(2,2)$ wrt both objectives, it must be the case that
$$\begin{align}
3x_1+x_2 &> 3(2) + (2)\\
-x_1 + 2x_2&>-(2)+ 2(2)
\end{align}\tag a
$$
Rewrite system (a) into the form:
$$\begin{align}
3(x_1-2)+(x_2-2) &> 0\\
-(x_1-2) + 2(x_2- 2)&>0
\end{align}\tag b
$$
If we write $\beta$ for the LHS of the first inequality in (b) and $\alpha$ for the LHS of the second inequality, then we are requiring $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$. Solve the LHS of system (b) for $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to obtain a characterization of all points $(x_1,x_2)$ better than $(2,2)$:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1-2=-\frac17\alpha +\frac27\beta\\
x_2-2=\frac37\alpha+\frac17\beta
\end{align}\tag c
$$
After relabeling $\lambda_1:=\frac\alpha7$ and $\lambda_2:=\frac\beta7$, the equations (c) are exactly the ones in point 2.